# Why python limits signals to the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

Comes from cpython [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/signalmodule.c#L63):

> - only the main thread can set a signal handler
> - any thread can get a signal handler
> - signals are only delivered to the main thread

This explains *what* it is doing, but not *why* it is doing so.

So why only the main thread can set a signal handler and handle signals? Does this come with benefits or due to restrictions?

Comment: @unutbu: Whichever thread receives the signal, the main thread executes the Python-level signal handler.

Comment: @user2357112: I could be wrong but the comments make it sound like on Solaris SIGINT may not be sent to the main thread, only to a random thread.

Comment: @unutbu: Yeah, but the C signal handler sets a flag that tells the main thread to execute the Python signal handler.